# how to set timer of setInterval on jquery from the record of mysql database?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how to set timer of setInterval on jquery from the record of mysql database?
here i have a table on mysql database with following columns

```
---------+-------------+-------------
| ID     + slidename   + displayfor |
---------+-------------+-------------
| 1      + slide 1     + 3000       |
| 2      + slide 2     + 10000      |
-------------------------------------
```

i am using one page scroll with fixed timer on setInterval. i want to replace the fixed timer with the above displayfor data

```
<?php
        $getslides="select * from slides";
        $slides=$db->query($getslides);
        $countRows = $db->num_rows($slides);
        $c=0;
        while($setslides=$db->fetch_object($slides))
        { 
           $c++;
        ?>
            <script>
                var x=0;
                var last = <?php echo $countRows; ?>;
                    sliding = function(){
                        x++;
                        if(x<=last)
                        {
                            $("a[data-index="+x+"]").trigger("click"); 
                            $('#'+x).trigger('click');              
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            x=0;
                            $('#'+x).trigger('click');
                        }
                    }
                    setInterval(sliding, 5000);
            </script>
        <?php
        }
?>
```

i want to change setInterval's 5000 to the record of displayfor. 
is there any method to change the interval time with the database record

Comment: Try splitting your php away from your JavaScript and fetch your slides using `$.getJSON()` which calls a php script generating the JSON string (see [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/json_encode))